# How to call function from class in apscheduler job?

Tags: python, apscheduler

I have a `class` that has triggers, and I'd like to update these triggers when the job hit the proper time.

My class:

```
class SetTrigger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.set_work = False
        self.set_reload = False
        self.set_refresh = False
    
    def UpdateSetRefresh(self):
        self.set_refresh = True
        return self.set_refresh

    def UpdateSetWork(self):
        self.set_work = True
        return self.set_work

    def UpdateSetReload(self):
        self.set_reload = True
        return self.set_reload
```

If I set the variable to get the value from the function as below I get one error.

```
trigger = SetTrigger()
set_refresh = trigger.UpdateSetRefresh()
```

Error:

```
func must be a callable or a textual reference to one
```

I already tried to call `trigger.UpdateSetRefresh` but the variable `set_refresh` doesn't change to `True`. If I call `trigger.UpdateSetRefresh()` it gives me the same error above.

How can I call the function `UpdateSetRefresh` from class `SetTrigger` in APScheduler job as below?

I tried:

```
scheduler.add_job(trigger.UpdateSetRefresh, 'interval', seconds=20, id='1', name='refresh_hereoes_positions', misfire_grace_time=180)
```

[EDIT]

Example that `trigger.UpdateSetRefresh` is not returning `True` as I need:

```
import tzlocal
import time
import os
from bot import SetTrigger
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler

trigger = SetTrigger()

scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(timezone=str(tzlocal.get_localzone()))
scheduler.add_job(trigger.UpdateSetRefresh, 'interval', seconds=3)
scheduler.start()
print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))

try:
    # This is here to simulate application activity (which keeps the main thread alive).
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        print(trigger.set_refresh)
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    # Not strictly necessary if daemonic mode is enabled but should be done if possible
    scheduler.shutdown()
```

Output:

```
Press Ctrl+Break to exit
False
False
False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass function to `add_job` but instead of it you passed returned value of the `trigger.UpdateSetRefresh`.
So correct statement would be like:

```
scheduler.add_job(trigger.UpdateSetRefresh, 'interval', seconds=2, id='1', name='refresh_hereoes_positions')
```

instead of

```
scheduler.add_job(trigger.UpdateSetRefresh(), 'interval', seconds=2, id='1', name='refresh_hereoes_positions')
```

When you add parentheses at the end of the function name python will execute it and pass returned value to the `add_job` function.
For more information about passing function as argument check out this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/passing-function-as-an-argument-in-python/).

[EDIT]
If you are using AsyncIOScheduler
you should do something like this

```
import tzlocal
import os
from bot import SetTrigger
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
import asyncio


def DisplayValue(trigger):
    print(trigger.UpdateSetWork())


trigger = SetTrigger()
scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(timezone=str(tzlocal.get_localzone()))
scheduler.add_job(trigger.UpdateSetRefresh, 'interval', seconds=3)
scheduler.start()
print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))


try:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.call_at(10, displayValue, trigger)
    loop.run_forever()
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    scheduler.shutdown()
```

Or you can use Background scheduler like that

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from bot import SetTrigger
import tzlocal
import time

trigger = SetTrigger()
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.configure(timezone=str(tzlocal.get_localzone()))
scheduler.add_job(trigger.UpdateSetRefresh, 'interval', seconds=2, id='1', name='refresh_hereoes_positions')
scheduler.start()

while True:
    print(trigger.set_refresh)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: If I call `trigger.UpdateSetRefresh` and `print(trigger.set_refresh)` the value is still `False`, how can this value turned into `True` by this way? If I cannot call `trigger.UpdateSetRefresh()`

Comment: Did you started scheduler?
`scheduler.start()`

Comment: Yes! Check the EDIT in my question to see the output please.

Comment: Still how can I get `trigger.set_refresh` value as `True`? By your answer I'm still getting as `False` and value is not being updated.

Comment: Check out new edition if it doesn't help you, I don't know how to fix your issue :/

Comment: For some reason and I don't know why, it works with `scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()` but not with `scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()`. Thank you anyway!